Difference between “new” and “young”
As far as I understand it, “new” in its objective sense describes what has started existing recently. It can be understood also as a relation, like “my new bicycle” describes the bicycle as new to me because I recently started having it.
“young” seems to mean the same as “new” in the objective sense but limited to people or personified objects, because, when I try to define “young”, I say something like “a person which has started existing recently”, which is like the definition of “new” but limited to persons. I also used “started existing” instead of “been born” or “been conceived” to avoid the issue of when people start existing.
These definitions are compatible with what I found in dictionaries. But I never encountered that someone would use “new” to mean “young”. Is there a difference between “young person” and “new person” in the objective sense? According to these definitions, no, and I can use “new” in all cases when I use “young” because “new” is more general. How do people understand these words?

'Young' is not 'limited to people or personified objects'. The word can be used about animals and plants.

We have a new person in our group today. She is not young. That's all  you need.

There are some contexts where "new" can mean "young", but not usually with people.

You don't need to worry about saying 'being born', because we don't call an unborn baby 'young'.

When a new person comes to your chess club, there's no implication that [s]he is a young person.

@Barmar According to the IMO reasonable definition in the answer by Canadian Yankee (“Generally, young is used for anything in the early stages of a natural aging process that eventually results in maturity.”), unborn babies are young.

People who downvoted my question, please, let me know why.

That was Kate's comment, not mine.  But I wouldn't call a fetus young, either. However, I could imagine anti-abortionists doing so because they like to use language that treats them as people, to support their ideology.

And I don't think Canadian Yankee meant for that description to apply to unborn babies, either. I have never in my life heard anyone say "young fetus".

Generally, young is used for anything in the early stages of a natural aging process that eventually results in maturity. It can be a person, as you say, but animals, plants, cheese, or wine can all be described as "young" in the sense of "not very mature".  A colt is a young male horse; a Beaujolais nouveau is a variety of young red wine.  For anything that does not have a natural aging process, "young" is not used (e.g., you do not usually say that you have a "young car").
The word new is applied to something that has had a recent transition from absence to presence. As mentioned in the comments, it is natural to say, "There is a new person joining our group today." This says nothing about their age, nor does it imply that they were just born. It means that they are newly added to the group.
You also might say, "I feel like a new man!" which doesn't mean that you feel like you were just born; it means that you feel like a different (usually better, happier, or healthier) person than you were not so long ago.
The only time you'd use new to refer to age would be in a sentence like, "Sally just had a new baby," but that's less about saying that the baby is young than it is calling attention to the transition from "no baby" to "existing baby". Sally is called a "new mother" by the same logic.

You express the idea of what “young” means well. But it still seems that all young entities are also new because I think that it is not possible to become young are being not young, so it would be correct to call young entities new, although more vague.

@matj1 "Young" can also be relative. A "young couple" can be in their early 20s (because that is young for being married), but they're not "new" in the sense of being newborns.
